# Display line breaks in table contents

Tags: html, line-breaks

i have an HTML like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td>      

Name: 
Rica

Lastname: 
Florentino 

Amount: 
3,000 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I be able to display it as is? The output seems to convert the newlines as spaces.. The output I'm getting is:

```
Name: Rica Lastname: Florentino Amount: 3,000
```

It should be:

```
Name: 
Rica

Lastname: 
Florentino 

Amount: 
3,000
```

Comment: Just add some `<br/>` tags! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksdJb/)

Comment: Is this the real `table` markup (one cell only)? Is it fixed? It seems odd to wrap tabular inside a single table cell with no markup inside it and to have it displayed in such a format. But if this is really the situation, then use `white-space: pre` in CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well , you can add `<br>` in between

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
 <td>      
   Name: 
   Rica
    <br>
   Lastname: 
   Florentino 
    <br>
   Amount: 
   3,000 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or manage it with css

**updated**

```
$(function(){
  $('#mytable td').css({'white-space': 'pre-line'});
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uepdw/1/)

Comment: You're still missing a few in order to output what the OP wanted. Furthermore why the unnecessary `/` in the tag?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 well `<br />`is beacuse  some systems that generate HTML may be based on XML generators, and thus not have the ability to output just a bare <br> tag. `<br />`works in such cases.. but since i assume this is not the case here for OP.. deleted the extra `/`

Comment: The output is already displayed so how can I AUTOMATICALLY convert the spaces or atleast retain the pre formatted data? also the title has been modified..

Comment: update my code .. this is using jquery css()

Comment: Thanks bipen.. this actually worked. this is what im looking for. :-)

Comment: The “updated” answer is completely different from the original answer, and it pointlessly relies on JavaScript *and* uses jQuery when one simple CSS rule would suffice to produce the effect.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to manually inserting `<br>` elements, you can use CSS to do this:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
 <td style="white-space: pre-line;">      
   Name: 
   Rica

   Lastname: 
   Florentino 

   Amount: 
   3,000 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uepdw/). Also, you may wish to read more about the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

If you have more than one cell, I suggest using a stylesheet instead of the `style` element.

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of linebreaks??

```
<br />
```

will create a html linebreak.
insert this any time you wish to do a linebreak ;)

and if all else fails you can use preformatted text:

```
<pre>
  Your text: 
  Lorem Ipsum
</pre>
```

this will just dump your formatted text the way it is in code to the browser.
most of the time there is a different font associated with it in the default browser stylesheet though.

well given the case you have some css, you can clear that browser stylesheet as follows:

```
*{
 /* selects all elements */
 /* insert your default stuff here */
 }
```

for changing the html content of elements use `.html()`
call this line once on page load and it should insert `pre`-tags at the beginning and the end of your table cell

```
$('#mytable tr td').html("<pre>" + $('#mytable tr td').html() + "</pre>")
```

it might be difficult to maintain the formatting either way, because sometimes your generated html gets optimized before it is sent to the client. this means you could lose the formatting in your code already.

instead you should try to change the html generation server-sided and use linebreak tags there.

Comment: i need to add pre tag on that data using jquery. or atleast convert spaces to <br> because the output is already displayed

Answer (score 0):

Put br tag

```
    <table id="mytable">
     <tr>
    <td>      

      Name: 
     <br>
     Rica
     <br>
     Lastname: 
     <br>
      Florentino 
      <br>

      Amount: 
      <br>
      3,000 
     </td>
   </tr>
    </table>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa4gV/)